# Visual Studio Code installation error on Ubuntu18.04 32-bit: "snap "code" is not available on stable for this architecture (i386)"

Tags: visual-studio-code, ubuntu-18.04, i386

I get the below error while trying to install Visual Studio Code on Ubuntu 18.04 32bit:

```
error: snap "code" is not available on stable for this architecture (i386)
       but exists on other architectures (amd64).
```

[image: VSCode Installation Error]

Comment: That message seems pretty clear. What part in particular are you having trouble with?

Comment: Hi, welcome to stackoverflow. You will be amazed on how good google is if you simply copy and paste the entire error message into the search box. If you are still not sure what to do after the google search, list out what you have attempted to solve it, and why does the tutorials/solutions from google search doesn't seems to fix your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since VS Code started using Electron 4.x+, it does not anymore run on Linux 32-bit.

It starts with this ticket in VS Code's Github issue:
[Electron 4.0.x does not run on 32bit Linux](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/66271)

> Closing as designed, with Electron 4 we will no longer support Linux 32bits. See https://electronjs.org/blog/linux-32bit-support

Following that blog post from Electron:
[Discontinuing support for 32-bit Linux](https://www.electronjs.org/blog/linux-32bit-support):

> The Electron team will discontinue support for 32-bit Linux (ia32 / i386) starting with Electron v4.0. The last version of Electron that supports 32-bit based installations of Linux is Electron v3.1, which will receive support releases until Electron v6 is released.

That is why the snap store only provides an amd64 installation.

[image]

This upgrade to Electron 4.x was mentioned in VS Code's release for 1.36.
https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_36#_linux-32bit-support-ends

> With this release, we move to Electron version 4.x, which means that VS Code will no longer run on Linux 32-bit. Please [update](https://code.visualstudio.com/download) to a 64-bit version of VS Code.

So.. your only option is to use an older version *before* 1.36.
Start with the 1.35 release:
https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_35