# How to install VS Code in Debian 11 with i386 architecture?

Tags: visual-studio-code, 32-bit

I have tried downloading the .deb file from VS Code site (all three formats), tried with terminal

```
sudo apt install code
sudo apt install code --classic
```

nothing worked...
please guide

Comment: I had an i386 computer in 1996. It had 4Mb of RAM and a 400Mb hard drive. Unfortunately, I did not try to run Linux on it. But MSDOS worked well.

Comment: why on earth do you use 32-bit Linux nowadays? All x86 CPUs you can buy in the last 2 decades are 64-bit. 32-bit x86 support has been removed from many Linux distros and most Linux apps for years, including Electron, therefore [VS Code can't be run on 32-bit x86 Linux](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/supporting/faq#_previous-release-versions)

Comment: duplicates: [Can I install Visual Studio Code on Ubuntu 32 bit?](https://askubuntu.com/q/616797/253474), [Cannot install Visual Studio Code on Debian Linux (i386)](https://superuser.com/q/1670391/241386), [Is it possible to install Visual Studio Code on Debian 10 buster 32-bit machine?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/650911/44425), [Visual Studio Code installation error on Ubuntu18.04 32-bit: "snap "code" is not available on stable for this architecture (i386)"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60714836/995714)